# Error "caution: filename not matched" - unzip command

Tags: linux, jar, archive, unzip

I am trying to unzip specific files from an archive.

Steps:

ZIP structure

```
 Archive:  folder/jce_policy-6.zip   9101 bytes   5 files
drwxr-xr-x  2.2 unx        0 bx stor 17-Nov-06 02:10 jce/
-r--r--r--  2.2 unx     2663 tx defN 17-Nov-06 02:10 jce/COPYRIGHT.html
-r--r--r--  2.2 unx     8386 tx defN 17-Nov-06 02:10 jce/README.txt
-rw-r--r--  2.2 unx     2465 bx defN 17-Nov-06 02:10 jce/US_export_policy.jar
-rw-r--r--  2.2 unx     2481 bx defN 17-Nov-06 02:10 jce/local_policy.jar
```

Copy JAR files:

```
unzip -o -j vendor/jce_policy-6.zip "*/*.jar" folder1/*.jar

Archive:  vendor/jce_policy-6.zip
  inflating: US_export_policy.jar
  inflating: local_policy.jar
caution: filename not matched:  folder1/*.jar
```

If I try `unzip -o -j vendor/jce_policy-6.zip "*/*.jar" folder1/*`

```
Archive:  vendor/jce_policy-6.zip
      inflating: US_export_policy.jar
      inflating: local_policy.jar
    caution: filename not matched:  folder1/<list the files in the folder>
```

I googled as much as I could, but I am not sure I found the correct one. How can I do it?

Comment: There ain't anything named like folder1/xxx in your zip, so you can't extract it via unzip. If you want to add it instead of extracting, try zip

Comment: `folder1` is present. but i did not use the option -d , after using that, it works. `unzip -o -j vendor/jce_policy-6.zip "*/*.jar" -d folder1/` . thanks.

Comment: I mean "It is not present in the archive": unzip does not care if it is present on the filesystem unless you specify -d.

Comment: yes. understood.

Comment: Duplication of a question on SuperUser: https://superuser.com/q/563215/312094

Answer (score 11):

I have a solution.

The above error indicates that you used the unzip command wrongly. Your shell expands the command ‘unzip *.zip’ as follows:

```
unzip a.zip b.zip c.zip
```

The solution:

```
unzip '*.zip'
```

Doing this shell doesn’t recognize it’s a [wildcard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character) character.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the case was a *space*. I had to rename my project name and remove that space and done.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution on another site.  The `*` symbol must be escaped, so you should run this instead:

```bash
unzip \\*.zip
```